# How to find YearMonth is equal or after current month?

Tags: java, datetime, date

I want to find the month is equal or after the current YearMonth

```
final YearMonth yearMonth = YearMonth.of(2020, 8);
final boolean after = yearMonth.isAfter(YearMonth.now());
```

Here current month is August(8) and I tried isAfter which returns false.

I want to return true for current month also.

Is any method is there in YearMonth itself?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just use the negation of the [`isBefore`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/YearMonth.html#isBefore(java.time.YearMonth)) method:

```
final boolean equalOrAfter = !yearMonth.isBefore(YearMonth.now());
```

After all a YearMonth can either be before, after or equal to another YearMonth, so if a YearMonth is **not** before another YearMonth it has to be either equal to or after it.

Comment: Well, I'm pretty certain someone must have miss-clicked – not me by the way. Oh, the downvote is gone.

Answer (score -1):

```
return yearMonth.getMonth().getValue()>= YearMonth.now().getMonth().getValue();
```

Comment: Except that also returns `true` for `yearMonth = YearMonth.of(2019, 8);`

Comment: This is simply false due it just compares the month but not the year it is in.